# How to properly load a Database row into a class in php

Tags: php, oop, kohana

I am using Kohana 3.2, not that it matters much, but I am writing an application where I am wrapping any and all returned database records in a specific class.  I don't know that I understand the best way to load the database row into the class, because sometimes it is a ORM model and sometimes it might just be an row ID.

So from a controller if I wanted a list of all the users it would look something like:

Controller:

```
$users = User::find_all();
```

User Class

```
public static function find_all()
{
    $users_model = ORM::factory('user')->find_all();
    $users = array();
    foreach ($users_model as $user_model)
    {
        $users[] = User::instance($user_model);
    }
    return $users;
}
```

That works great, but sometimes I need to load a user object with just an id, like after some action, again a example:

Controller

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$user = User::instance($user_id);
```

So is the User class responsible for trying to identify if an ID or a ORM object was passed into it.  It seems like that isn't right for good OOP practices, but I am really not sure what the best way to do it is.  What I have been currently doing is in the construct:

```
public function __construct($user, $load = 'model')
{
    if ($load == 'model')
    {
        $this->user_model = $user;
    }
    if ($load == 'id')
    {
        $this->user_model = ORM::factory('user', $user);
    }

}
```

But that really just doesn't feel right.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats the reason of this wrapping? Why dont use existing Model_User class for your needs?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a user model that extends ORM then you probably don't need static methods in the class to get all users or to get a particular user.

In your controller you can just do to get all the users

```
$users = ORM::factory('user')->find_all();
```

To get a single user

```
$user = ORM::factory('user', $user_id);
```

If you still want to go down the wrapping route you could use functions like so

```
public static function all() {
    $users = ORM::factory('user')->find_all();
    if (count($users)) {
        return $users;
    }
    return false;
}

public static function get($user_id) {
    $user = ORM::factory('user', $user_id);
    if ($user->id) {
        return $user;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, use the ORM to get the user based on the ID.

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$user = ORM::factory('user', $user_id);
```

Or given that you already have a find all in your user class, add a find_one() method:

User Class

```
public static function find_one($user_id)
{
    $user = ORM::factory('user', $user_id);
    return $user;
}
```

Controller

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$user = User::find_one($user_id);
```

See the Kohana docs.
http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/using#finding-an-object
http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/examples/simple

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user_model = is_object($user) ? $user : ORM::factory('user', (int)$user);
}
```